# onMouseDown not triggering useEffect

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to implement a draggable level meter by calling a function every 500ms if the user holds down the button. However, for some reason the `useEffect()` is only triggering if the button is released and I don't get the required effect.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useCallback, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { IonContent, IonHeader, IonPage, IonTitle, IonToolbar, IonToggle, IonList, IonItem, IonLabel, IonItemDivider } from '@ionic/react';
import useLongPress from './useLongPress';
import './LightController.css';
import { AppContext } from './../AppContextProvider';

export interface InterfaceLamp {
  id?: number,
  brightness: number,
  turnedOn: boolean,
}

const LightController: React.FC<InterfaceLamp> = (props) => {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(AppContext);

  const [isMouseDown, setMouseDown] = useState(false);
  const [interval, confInterval] = useState();


  useEffect(() => {
    if (isMouseDown) {
      let timeOut = setInterval(getPercentage, 500);
      confInterval(timeOut);
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [isMouseDown]);

  const getPercentage = () => {
    console.log('percentage')
  }

  return (
    <div className="c-light">
      <p>brightness</p>
      <div className="c-light__meter__wrapper"
        onMouseDown={(e) => setMouseDown(true)}
        onMouseUp={(e) => setMouseDown(false)}
      >
        <div className="c-light__meter">
        </div>
        <div className="c-light__meter__value">
          {props.brightness}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LightController;
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `useEffect` looks like it _should_ only be triggered on mouse down/up. `getPercentage` looks like the function that should be called every 500ms. Can you clarify?

Comment: I see a couple issues - the `else` branch within `useEffect` is not going to work. The `timerId` it has in scope will always be `undefined` since it's scoped to the closure within `useEffect`. Also, `clearTimeout` won't clear a `setInterval`, you'll want `clearInterval` for that.

Comment: @CameronLittle My bad. I updated the ```clearInterval```.

Answer (score 0):

**useDebounce.ts**

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function useDebounce<T>(
  initialValue: T,
  time: number
): [T, T, React.Dispatch<T>] {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<T>(initialValue);
  const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState<T>(initialValue);

  useEffect(() => {
    const debounce = setTimeout(() => {
      setDebouncedValue(value);
    }, time);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(debounce);
    };
  }, [value, time]);

  return [debouncedValue, value, setValue];
}
```

**LightController.ts**

```js
const [debouncedMouseDown, isMouseDown, setMouseDown] = useDebounce<boolean>(false, 500);

useEffect(() => {
  // do something
}, [debouncedMouseDown])

// rest omitted
```

Elegant approach suggested from [Nick Scialli](https://dev.to/nas5w/writing-a-custom-react-usedebounce-hook-with-typescript-ab)

Also, see [use-lodash-debounce](https://github.com/gnbaron/use-lodash-debounce)